# Facebook API disrupting rest of page until it loads data

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK to provide some features, but it's making the functionality of the rest of the page lag out/not work until it's done loading. To experience this, please go on http://beta.speedsums.com and click the (poorly placed) Facebook login button and then try to click inside the answer box. Alternatively, you may be able to spot something from the code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

<title>Speedsums - do maths fast</title>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-46469577-1', 'speedsums.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style type="text/css">

css stuff

</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.runner-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.animate-colors-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data2;
var jsonn;
var myLine;

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var fbid;var fbid = 0;

var operators = ['+','-','x','\xF7'];

var properties = {
   borderColor: 'green',
   borderWidth: '3px',
   height: '37px'
};

var user = {};
var friends = [];
var friendscores = [];
var friendpics = [];
var fbconnect;
var operand1;
var operand2;
var operator;
var answers;
var time;
var name;
var one;
var two;
var iteration = 0;
var unique;
var times = [];
var start;
var finish;

function drawuserchart(id){
    console.log('drawuserchart() initialised');
    $.ajax({
          url: 'userchart.php',
          data: {id: id},
          type: 'post',
          dataType:"json",
          success: function(data22){
            console.log(data22);

            var labelarray = new Array();

            for (var i=0;i<data22.length;i++) { 
                labelarray.push("");
            }


                data2 = {
                    labels : labelarray,
                    datasets : [
                        {
                            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                            strokeColor : "rgba(131,167,185,1)",
                            data : data22
                        }
                    ]
                }

                var options = {

    //Boolean - If we show the scale above the chart data           
    scaleOverlay : false,


}

                myLine2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("userchart").getContext("2d")).Line(data2,options);

            }, error: function(xhr,err){
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
}
    });
}

function generateproblems(number){

    operand1 = []; operand2 = []; operator = []; answers = [];

    for (var i=0; i < number; i++){

        //generating questions

        operator.push(operators[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);

        if (operator[i] == '\xF7'){
            denominator = Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
            numerator = denominator * Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
            operand1.push(numerator);
            operand2.push(denominator);
        } else if (operator[i] == '-'){
            one = Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
            two = Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
            operand1.push(Math.max(one,two));
            operand2.push(Math.min(one,two));
        } else {
            operand1.push(Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1));
            operand2.push(Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1));
        }

        //calculating answers

        if (operator[i] == '+'){
            answers.push(operand1[i] + operand2[i]);
        } else if (operator[i] == '-'){
            answers.push(operand1[i] - operand2[i]);
        } else if (operator[i] == 'x'){
            answers.push(operand1[i] * operand2[i]);
        } else if (operator[i] == '\xF7'){
            answers.push(operand1[i] / operand2[i]);
        }

    }

}

function runtest(number){
    $('#question').append('' + operand1[iteration] + ' ' + operator[iteration] + ' ' + operand2[iteration] + ' = ');
    $('#answer').keyup(function() {
        if ($('#answer').val() == answers[iteration]){

            finish = Date.now();
            times.push(finish-start);
            console.log(finish-start)
            if(iteration == 0){
                start = Date.now();
                $('#runner').runner('start');
                $('#counter').html(iteration);
            };
            iteration++;
            correct(number);
        }
    });
}

function percentile(score){
    $.ajax({
          url: 'percentile.php',
          data: {score: score},
          type: 'post',
          success: function(data){
            $('#percentile').html('You beat <b>'+ data +'% </b>of people.');
            }
    });
}



function correct(number){
    if(iteration == number){
        $('#runner').runner('stop');
        $('#runner').append('s');
        time = parseInt($('#runner').html()) / (number - 1);
        $('#runner').prepend('Total time: ');
        $('body').append('Time per question: ' + time + 's');
        stoptest();
    } else {
        $('#question').empty();
        $('#counter').html(iteration);
        $('#answer').val('');
        $('#question').append('' + operand1[iteration] + ' ' + operator[iteration] + ' ' + operand2[iteration] + ' = ');
        start = Date.now();
    }
}

function stoptest(){
    operand1 = [];
    operand2 = [];
    answers = [];
    operator = [];
    $('#question').remove();
    $('#answer').remove();
    console.log(times);
}

function gethighscore(id){
    $.ajax({
          async: false,
          url: 'gethighscore.php',
          data: {id: id},
          type: 'post',
          success: function(data){
            friendscores.push(data);
            console.log(data);
            }
    });
}

function getuserhighscore(id){
    $.ajax({
          async: false,
          url: 'gethighscore.php',
          data: {id: id},
          type: 'post',
          success: function(data){
            user['highscore'] = data;
            }
    });
}

function userpercentile(score){
    $.ajax({
          url: 'percentile.php',
          async: false,
          data: {score: score},
          type: 'post',
          success: function(data){
            user['percentile'] = data;
        }
    });
}

function post(name,score,unique){
    $.ajax({
          url: 'post.php',
          data: {name: name, score: score, unique: unique},
          type: 'post',
          success: function(data){
            $('#main').html('');
            $('#main').append('<br><br><br><br><span id="message">Submitted! ok now try again</span><br><br>');
            $('#main').append('<div id="restart">restart</div>');
            }
    });
}

function logg(score,unique,fb){
    console.log('attempting to log');
    $.ajax({
          url: 'log.php',
          data: {score: score, unique: unique, fb: fb},
          type: 'post',
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            }
    });
}

function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function portrait(){
    console.log('success');
}

$(document).ready(function(){


$.ajax({
     url: 'total.php',
     data: {},
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('.total').append('<b>'+numberWithCommas(data)+'</b>');
          }
    });

$('#form').hide();

$('#runner').runner({
    countdown: true,
    startAt: 30 * 1000,
    stopAt: 0
}).on('runnerFinish', function(eventObject, info) {
    times[0] = 0;
    times[times.length - 1] = 0;
    if(times[2] == times[3] == times[4] == times[5]){
        window.location.replace("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_(computer_security)");
    }
    unique = 15*iteration + 4;
    percentile(iteration);
    logg(iteration,unique,fbid);
    var slowesttime = Math.max.apply(Math,times);
    var position = times.indexOf(slowesttime);
    var slowestq = '' + operand1[position] + ' ' + operator[position] + ' ' + operand2[position] + '';
    var slowesta = answers[position];
    $('#counter, #solidus, #runner').remove();
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'});
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn("fast");
    if(fbconnect == true){
        $('#sidebar').fadeIn("fast");
    } 
    $('#score').append('<div id="results1">Total: <b>' + iteration + '</b></div>');
    $('#score').append('<div id="percentile"></div>');
    $('#score').append('<div id="other">Time per question: <b>' + (30/iteration).toFixed(2) + 's</b></div>');
    $('#score').append('<div id="other">For future reference, <b>' + slowestq + ' = ' + slowesta + '</b>. It should not take <b>' + (slowesttime/1000).toFixed(2) + 's</b> to solve that next time. </div>');
    $('#form').show();
    $('#tweet').click(function(){
        window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=omg+i+just+did+'+iteration+'+maths+problems+in+30s!+try+and+beat+me!&hashtags=speedsums&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.speedsums.com', 'Tweet', "height=300,width=500");
    });
    stoptest();


});

generateproblems(120);
runtest(120);

$('#answer').focus(function(){
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#BDC3C7'});
    $('#wrapper').fadeOut("fast");
    $('#instructions').fadeOut("fast");
    $('#sidebar').fadeOut("fast");
});

$('#answer').blur(function(){
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn("fast");
    $('#instructions').fadeIn("fast");
    if(fbconnect == true){
        $('#sidebar').fadeIn("fast");
    }
    $('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'});
});

$('#post').click(function(){
    name = $('#name').val();
    unique = 15*iteration + 4;
    post(name,iteration,unique);
});

$('body').on('click','#restart, #retry', function() {
        window.location.href = "index.html";
});

//Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
//This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);

var ctx2 = $("#userchart").get(0).getContext("2d");
//This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
var userchart = new Chart(ctx2);


$.ajax({
          url: 'distribution.php',
          data: {},
          type: 'get',
          dataType:"json",
          success: function(data22){


            var dataarray = new Array();

            for (var i=0;i<46;i++) { 
            dataarray.push(data22[i]);
            }


                data2 = {
                    labels : ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42"],
                    datasets : [
                        {
                            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            data : dataarray
                        }
                    ]
                }

                var options = {

                    //Boolean - If we show the scale above the chart data           
                    scaleOverlay : false,

                }

                myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")).Bar(data2,options);

            }
    });

});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>


<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to
  present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked.<span class="total">Total sums done: </span> -->


<div id="header"><div class="page"><a class="nav1">TEST</a><div id="logo"></div><a class="nav2">PRACTICE</a><div id="thumbnail"><div class="fb-login-button" id="fbloginbutton" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div></div></div></div><div id="sidebar" style="display:none"><h2>FRIENDS</h2><div id="friendcontainer"></div><div id="statscontainer"><h2>YOUR STATS</h2></div><canvas id="userchart" width="250" height="200"></canvas></div>

<div id="notice">Speedsums is under renovation - there's gonna be a bunch of cool new stuff soon, so keep checking back! -Taimur</a></div>

<br><div class="instructions"><span id="instructions">Click inside the box below to begin</span></div><div id="spacer"></div>


<div id="main">

<div id="question"></div><br>
<div><input id="answer" type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><br>

<div id="runner"></div><span id="solidus">/</span><div id="counter">0</div>
<div id="score"></div>

<div id="form">
<div id="tweet">Tweet Score</div><br>
<div id="retry">Retry</div>
</div><br><br>
</div>


<canvas id="myChart" width="1440" ></canvas>
<script>
// Include the UserVoice JavaScript SDK (only needed once on a page)
UserVoice=window.UserVoice||[];(function(){var uv=document.createElement('script');uv.type='text/javascript';uv.async=true;uv.src='//widget.uservoice.com/aIRVe5TPDRSYNkW7H1CAg.js';var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv,s)})();

//
// UserVoice Javascript SDK developer documentation:
// https://www.uservoice.com/o/javascript-sdk
//

// Set colors
UserVoice.push(['set', {
  accent_color: '#448dd6',
  trigger_color: 'white',
  trigger_background_color: '#448dd6'
}]);

// Identify the user and pass traits
// To enable, replace sample data with actual user traits and uncomment the line
UserVoice.push(['identify', {
  //email:      'john.doe@example.com', // User’s email address
  //name:       'John Doe', // User’s real name
  //created_at: 1364406966, // Unix timestamp for the date the user signed up
  //id:         123, // Optional: Unique id of the user (if set, this should not change)
  //type:       'Owner', // Optional: segment your users by type
  //account: {
  //  id:           123, // Optional: associate multiple users with a single account
  //  name:         'Acme, Co.', // Account name
  //  created_at:   1364406966, // Unix timestamp for the date the account was created
  //  monthly_rate: 9.99, // Decimal; monthly rate of the account
  //  ltv:          1495.00, // Decimal; lifetime value of the account
  //  plan:         'Enhanced' // Plan name for the account
  //}
}]);

// Add default trigger to the bottom-right corner of the window:
UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', { mode: 'satisfaction', trigger_position: 'top-left' }]);

// Or, use your own custom trigger:
//UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', '#id', { mode: 'satisfaction' }]);

// Autoprompt for Satisfaction and SmartVote (only displayed under certain conditions)
UserVoice.push(['autoprompt', {}]);
</script>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '219892158204692',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below
  // will be handled.
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs.
    if (response.status === 'connected') {

        if(fbconnect == true){

        } else {

        fbconnect = true;
        $('#fbloginbutton').hide();
        $('#friendcontainer').append('<span id="loader"><center>Loading...</center></span>');
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they
      // have logged in to the app.
        FB.api(
            "/me",
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                fbid = response['id'];
                user['id'] = response['id'];
                getuserhighscore(user['id']);
                userpercentile(parseInt(user['highscore']));
                $('#statscontainer').append('<span class="label">Highest Score</span>: '+user['highscore']+'<br>');
                $('#statscontainer').append('<span class="label">Percentile (global)</span>: '+user['percentile']+'<br>');
                drawuserchart(user['id']);

                }
            }
        );



        FB.api(
            "/fql?q=select%20uid%2C%20first_name%2C%20is_app_user%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20in%20(select%20uid2%20from%20friend%20where%20uid1%3Dme())%20and%20is_app_user%3D1",
            function (response) {
                console.log('friends installed:');
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response['data'][0].id);
                var responseArray = []; 
                responseArray.push(response);
                console.log(responseArray); 
                user['friends'] = response['data'].length;
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    for (var i=0;i<response['data'].length;i++){
                        friend = response['data'][i];
                        console.log('friend coming up');
                        console.log(friend);
                        friends.push(friend.uid);
                        $('#friendcontainer').append('<div class="friendbox" id="'+friend.uid+'"></div>');
                           $('#'+friend.uid+'').append('<img class="friendpic" src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+friend.uid+'/picture?height=60&width=60&type=square">');
                           $('#'+friend.uid+'').append('<div class="friendname">'+friend.first_name+'</div>');
                        gethighscore(friend.uid);
                        $('#'+friend.uid+'').append(' - '+friendscores[i]+'');
                        console.log(friendscores);
                    }
                    $('#loader').remove();

                    user['friendrank'] = 1;



                    for (var i=0;i<friendscores.length;i++){
                        if(friendscores[i] > user['highscore']){
                            user['friendrank']++;
                        }
                    }

                    $('#statscontainer').append('<span class="label">Rank (among friends)</span>: '+user['friendrank']+'<br>');

                } else { 
                    console.log(response.error) 
                }
            }
        );
        console.log(friends);
        console.log(user)
        FB.api(
            "/me/picture",
            {
                "redirect": false,
                "height": "100",
                "type": "normal",
                "width": "100"
            },
            function (response) {
              if (response && !response.error) {
                user['picture'] = response['data']['url'];
                console.log(user['picture']);
                $('#thumbnail').append('<img id="thumbnailpic" src="'+user['picture']+'">');
              }
            }
        );
    }
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so.
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login()
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook.
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful.
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      $('#sidebar').slideDown("slow");
    });
  }
</script>
</body>


</html>
```

Sorry that the code is so messy and bad - I'm not sure how much of the Javascript stuff I need to include for the problem to be diagnosed so I've just put it all in. I'm not sure why the Facebook stuff is disrupting everything else, because it's right at the very bottom of the page...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least I notice two things in your code:

1. The call of testAPI() is from my perspective unneccessary and "out of context"
2. You can save at least one API call if you combine the first with the third one like this

   FB.api('/me?fields=id,picture', function { ... });